Get Test Step Execution ID without UI
I a using Zephyr squad in Jira and I want to automate a process. I created a cycle, added test to it, got the relevant execution ID all using APIs but when I try to get the Test **Step **ID for that execution ID I just returns and empty array. As soon as I click on execute in the Jira UI it start returning the relevant data. I don't want that step of clicking Execute in UI as it completely defeats the purpose. Is there a way to execute the test using APIs.
I tried using a lot of different end points but none of them executed the test. I have all the relevant info, project id, issue id, cycle id, execution id etc. Thank You
